# How deep sync of string strings implemented in implementation in the standard template library?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, concurrency, stl

How does the standard template library **internally implement** synchronize the deep level of std::strings when it is implemented as reference pointers?
The user has to sync variable of type std::string when using it concurrently.

If you are talking to the same variable you must do the synchronization the standard template library by design is not going to synchronize a variable, on the other hand as is common with many implementations of string they have reference counted objects then the standard library is ensuring that any object shared between two variables is properly synchronized. So you are responsible for the shallow synchronization on the variable by any deep synchronization is the responsibility of the library.

Comment: I find your question quite confusing. Are you asking how [copy-on-write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) strings work? Edit: On second reading, perhaps you are asking how it is safe to use the same `std::string` from two threads?

Comment: What reference counted strings are you talking about?

Comment: Perhaps a code sample would help us understand what you're trying to ask?

Comment: the simplest answer : it doesn't

Comment: C++11 disallows reference counted strings.

Comment: @Damian Voted to close as "unclear what you're asking". Please try to clarify the question. As benjymous points out, a small code sample may help.

Comment: Updated the question so it is more clear, is that better?

Answer (score 0):

A `reference` in C++ is a pointer that is hidden from you to make it safer. Just like a pointer, it records where the object is located on your machine for future access.

`std::string` does not implement it is own reference. C++ does not allow you to write your own custom reference.

You can read more about references [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_%28C++%29).

Comment: While I fully admit to not being sure what the question is, I don't think it is about this.

Comment: @BoBTFish `std::string` header does have a `std::string::reference` which might be what the OP is talking about but that is just a typedef that is `char&`.